# Expanding an array in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return multiple elements from my helper `render` functions, but I don't want to add keys to each element. For example:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  _renderBar() {
    return [
      'hello ',
      <b>world</b>,
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this._renderBar()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Since JSX compiles to `React.createElement` calls, and `React.createElement` accepts elements as it's third and higher arguments, I want to spread the array returned by `_renderBar` when `React.createElement` is called.

For example, my code currently compiles to something like this:

```
React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  ['hello ', React.createElement(
    'b',
    null,
    'world'
  )]
);
```

Since I don't have keys on the array elements, I get a warning. I want it to be something like this:

```
React.createElement(
  "div",
  null,
  "hello ",
  React.createElement(
    "b",
    null,
    "world"
  )
);
```

I tried doing `{...this._renderBar()}`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this with JSX. The simplest solution would be to call `React.createElement` directly:

```
React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  ...this._renderBar()
);
```